# Where to put an artifact which will be used only by test

Tags: testing, project-structure

I am developing a new feature for a well-established memory package. The feature Im implementing is about loading/copying/moving resources in and out to different type of structures like jars, libraries and so.

I started with writing tests first. I felt i need an test artifact, like a sample file/DLL/txt whatever, however, I do not know where to put it? What is the best practice to follow in this type of situation?

Comment: Why not put it next to the tests?

Comment: I could do that. Would it be the best practice? I just want to learn the correct way of handling this.

Comment: There is rarely a single correct way of handling things in software engineering. This is a detail that can be adjusted later if your current choice turns out to be sub-optimal, so my advise it to choose something that looks logical to you and see how that works out.

Comment: I did it it that way for now. Will be updating if i need some other structure later. Thank you for your reply. Would you like to make it an answer down here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you to put it on your 'test' directory of your project, if the 'test' directory isn't flat (for instance 'mocks' 'unit' etc. as in Rails) I would create a directory called 'data'/'artifact' in there and put the file inside.

Moreover, please make sure to call the file in a name that corresponds to the actual test file. If this file is being used in many test files (with different names), I would advise you to document it so its' usage can be traced in case of cleanup/refactoring.

+There isn't a "best way" and each project is a special case, yet consistency and making it easier for future maintainers to make sense of this file can go a long way.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions and detailed answer. I followed something similar and working well for now.